# Better word for someone who has grown physically but not mentally

Tags: phrases

I don't mean someone who is totally mentally challenged. I am referring to ones whose mental growth is not proportional to the physical.

Comment: So, are we talking about a six-foot man with the mind of a five-year old or not? If we *are*, in what sense is he not "retarded/mentally challenged"? If we're *not*, exactly how much of a size/brainpower mismatch are we talking about here? I am asking in all seriousness, but I think the question is inevitably going to be Not Constructive.

Comment: @FumbleFingers , am referring to someone, who is not ready to consider himself fit to face the real world. And so stuck in the burrow. So - he had to stay in the shadow of his family. But - I want to use a polite sense, as he is THE GUY of my plot ;)

Comment: In that case it's very much Not Constructive. You obviously have your own understanding of what "mental growth" (or lack of it) actually means - most people aren't particularly likely to think of it as specifically meaning *having the qualities of self-confidence and independence needed to contemplate life outside one's birth family*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, consider - I want to revamp my definition to someone who could not grasp well, be it education or the reality of life. What word would you recommend ? Is "Intellectually challenged" a fit word ?

Comment: A fairly common idiom would be to say that someone is "25 going on 16", for example, for a person who is physically 25 but has the emotional development of a 16-year-old.  (It's an inversion of the also-popular "13 going on 30"-style phrasing, said of someone who is mature or sophisticated beyond their years.)

Comment: @satya: You could say your character is *childlike, cosseted, mollycoddled, home-loving, dependent,* etc. Or conversely, you could point out that he's ***not*** *mature, independent, self-confident,* etc. But I think in the end you have to decide how you want to describe whatever aspects of character you have in mind - there's nothing about English itself (or how native speakers think about children becoming independent adults) that would allow ELU to just identify and agree on the "right" word here.

Answer (score 2):

I think *immature* (as a general description of the individual, as opposed to being applied to any specific action of theirs) adequately describes the classic situation of someone who should be moving out on their own, but doesn't feel--or doesn't show evidence of being--ready to take the big step.

Answer (score 1):

*Mentally retarded* was originally the term for this, but euphemism creep has turned that into an unacceptable insult.

Having a [development disorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developmental_disorder) is commonly used now.

Comment: Autism - Development disorder, suits my case.
Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for *manchild*. This is more of a derogatory term, however.

A somewhat obscure one, borrowed from Japanese, is *hikikomori*, but this is perhaps more extreme than what you wanted.

Regarding staying home, *homebody* could be it.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like the following?

```
 He has the body of an adult and the mind of a child.
```

I do not think you can be more succinct and avoid the connotations of a medical condition.